# differences between (find . -name *.cpp) and (find . -name "*.cpp")

Tags: shell, find

I'm confused with these twe sentences:

A. `find . -name *.cpp`
B. `find . -name "*.cpp"`

The Regular Expression only works in situation B.
I'm glad to learn from U.Who can explain this,more details.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: see [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Prevent_field_splitting_and_ignore_glob_pattern_characters)

Answer (score 1):

Your focus here is on the parameter you pass to the "-name" option. We want "find", and not the encompassing Shell (bash / tcsh / zsh) to interpret it.

When you put the **"*.cpp"**, you actually allow the "find" program to see "*.cpp", then perform the transformation to a list of all files ending with ".cpp".

When you just put ***.cpp**, the Shell performs the replacement before even passing the parameter to the find command (that is called [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)). What the find command actually gets is not a pattern, but a set of files. Which leads to :

"find . **-name A.cpp** *B.cpp ... Z.cpp*"

The files with names in *italics* are NOT parameters of the "-name" flag, thus, the unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Christian.K: only jealousy can explain such a ruthless downvote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the first command, `*.cpp` is expanded by your shell, but in the second one, `*.cpp` is passed untouched to find, who can use it in every subdirectory to look for the correct files.

Let's say you have two subdirectories with C++ files:

```
a.cpp
e.cpp
sub1/
  b.cpp
  c.cpp
sub2/
  d.cpp
```

The first command (`find . -name *.cpp`) is equivalent to `find . -name a.cpp e.cpp`, which is not what you want! If there is no cpp file in the current directory, it will not find anything.

Another way to escape the `*` to prevent the shell from expanding it is to use: `find . -name \*.cpp`. It's not something that you should use, but it may help you to understand the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any .cpp files in the current directory where you run the find command, then without the quotes your shell will expand the wildcard and call

```
find . -name file1.cpp file2.cpp ...
```

With the quotes, the star gets passed through directly to find without expansion.

Answer (score 0):

> -name pattern
>             Base  of  file  name  (the  path  with  the  leading directories
>             removed) matches  shell  pattern  pattern.   The  metacharacters
>             ('*',  '?',  and '[]') match a '.' at the start of the base name
>             (this is a change in findutils-4.2.2; see section STANDARDS CON-
>             FORMANCE  below). [...]    **Don't    forget
>             to  enclose  the  pattern  in quotes in order to protect it from
>             expansion by the shell**.

From find manual

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes. Tactical downvoting is quite limited in SO, but it does happen.